# Row replacement in tibbles

Tags: r, shiny, tidyverse, tibble

Consider the following small piece of R code:

```
A = tibble(animal = 'cat',color = 'black',weight = 1000)

A[1,] <-   gsub("a","e",A[1,])
```

What I want is a one-row tibble with entries 'cet', 'bleck' and 1000, but trying to run this with tibble 3.0.3 loaded gives an error:

```
Error: Assigned data `gsub("a", "e", A[1, ])` must be compatible with row subscript `1`.

x 1 row must be assigned.

x Assigned data has 3 rows.

ℹ Row updates require a list value. Do you need `list()` or `as.list()`?*
```

...which I guess makes sense, as the gsub results in a length 3 character vector.

Here's my question: This piece of code is a small part of a R Shiny app I have running on a company server. Yesterday, after an admin installed the 'photobiology' package on the server, our app started to crash; digging into the code, the lines above turned out to be the cause of the problem. So, before installing some new packages, the code above was executed as we intended it, after installing the new package (with dependencies), we got errors. Rewriting the code is not a big issue, but I'd like to understand what went wrong, and I'm not too familiar with tibbles. Can it be that this type of row replacement was possible in an earlier version of the tibble package, but not in the most recent version?

Answer (score 0):

When you are updating a row of a tibble it expects you to pass

- a list or a dataframe/tibble
- they should have same column names as the original tibble (`A`)
- they should have the same class as the original tibble (`A`)

This is to ensure data uniformity is maintained and wrong values are not updated.

Combine all this and you can do :

```
tmp <- as.data.frame(t(gsub("a","e",A[1,])))
tmp <- type.convert(tmp, as.is = TRUE)
names(tmp) <- names(A)
A[1,]  <- tmp
A

# A tibble: 1 x 3
#  animal color weight
#  <chr>  <chr>  <dbl>
#1 cet    bleck   1000
```

Comment: Thanks for that. I realise that there are ways of getting around the error -- I'm more curious after what caused the error in the first place, since the code I posted worked until yesterday, and now suddenly does not.

Comment: `tibble` or `tidyverse` generally have been always stricter about types and names. I guess this is one more instance of it. I don't know all the changes that happened on your company server yesterday which caused things to not work but I am guessing tibbles allowed such row changes earlier which they have stopped now in line with their original principle. BTW the code works with a dataframe (`A = data.frame(animal = 'cat',color = 'black',weight = 1000)`) but since tibbles are stricter it doesn't allow such changes to happen.